# Не переключается класс на jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Пытался написать на чистом JS переключения класса, но ничего не вышло.

Решил уж и на JQuery, но это не работает также.

Я наблюдал за изменениями через *Просмотр кода*, но класс не поменялся.

Буду очень благодарен, если найдёте ошибку, особенно, если можно сделать это на чистом JS.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light" style="box-shadow:0 0 10px black;">
        <img width="80px" src="../img/logo3.png">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" id="toggle">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;" id="n">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Our blog</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</nav>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#toggle").click(function(){
    $("n").toggleClass("active");
})
```

Мы можете наблюдать здесь Bootstrap классы, знаю, можно было и через Bootstrap сделать, но это требует `bootstrap.css`, `bootstrap.min.css`, `bootstrap.js` и также `bootstrap.min.js`. Выгоднее написать на чистом JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если Вы хотели добавлять/удалять класс `active` у элемента с ID равным `n`, то Вы просто не дописали решетку вначале:

```
$("#toggle").on("click", function() {
  $("#n").toggleClass("active")
})
```

На JS:

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  document.querySelector("#n").classList.toggle("active")
}

document.querySelector("#toggle").addEventListener("click", handleClick)
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light" style="box-shadow:0 0 10px black;">
  <img width="80px" src="../img/logo3.png">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" id="toggle">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">click me</span>
        </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;" id="n">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Our blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Вот чёрт, у меня всегда были проблемы со знаками. Спасибо, что помогли, а уж особенно за код на JS!